# What is standalone function?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of the term “free function” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c)

I am not sure what a standalone function is.

Is it inside the class or same as normal function outside the main and class?

Comment: It's not a formal term. We've got a reasonable idea, but we'd probably call it a _free_ function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A stand-alone function is just a normal function that is not a member of any class and is in a global namespace. For example, this is a member function:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass add( SomeClass other );
};
SomeClass::add( SomeClass other )
{
    <...>
}
```

And this is a stand-alone one:

```
SomeClass add( SomeClass one, SomeClass two );
```

Comment: so the standalone function type must be the class? or like the normal function, you can name anything and get data from main?

Comment: @Rex, no it can be anything, this is just a random example ;)

Answer (score 3):

A stand-alone function is typically

- A global function which doesn't belong to any `class` or `namespace`.
- Serves a single purpose of doing something (like a utility, say `strcpy()`)

They should be used judiciously as too much of those will clutter the code.

Answer (score 3):

A standalone function is one which doesn't depend on any *visible* state:

```
int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Here `max` is a standalone function.

Standalone functions are stateless. In C++, they're referred to as *free* functions.