# Left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, templates

Still cannot get this one to work. Please help!

```
template <typename T>
class Container{
public:
    ...

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Container<T>& C)
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i!= data.size(); i++) // ERROR
            ostr<<data[i]<<" "; 
        return ostr;
    }

private:
    vector<T> data;
};
```

Comment: Huh?  Where is the MVP?

Comment: I don't see any MVP in here, but `data` is a part of `C`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth data.size() throws: "left of '.size' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: Sure.  But it's nothing to do with MVP.

Comment: @InnocentRetard, I can get the same error with `SomeClass *p; p.member();`

Comment: @InnocentRetard That's not MVP.  MVP refers to the ambiguity between "function prototype" and "initialization of variable by constructor."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is a member of `C` and should therefore be accessed as `C.data` (remember that your `operator<<` is a [free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c) and not a member of `Container`):

```
    for(size_t i = 0; i != C.data.size(); ++i)
        ostr << C.data[i] << " ";
```