# error C3861 Graphics CopyFromScreen:identifier not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using visual studio 2010 and i'm writing a code to capture a screen on a button click. i've written the code as

```
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         try
         {
             SaveFileDialog^ save = gcnew SaveFileDialog();
             save->Title = "Save Screenshot";
             save->Filter = "JPEG | *.jpg | Bitmap | *.bmp | Portable Network Graphics|*.png|Graphical Interchange File Format|*.gif";
             save->ShowDialog();
             pictureBox1->Image->Save(save->FileName);
         }
         catch(Exception^ ex)
         {
         MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);

         }


     }
private: System::Void Form1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
         if(e->KeyCode == System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Enter)
         {
             Rectangle^ bounds;
             System::Drawing::Bitmap^ screenshot;
             Graphics^ graph;
             bounds = Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds;
             screenshot = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(bounds->Width,bounds->Height, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppArgb);
             graph = Graphics::FromImage(screenshot);
             graph = CopyFromScreen (bounds->X, bounds->Y, 0, 0, bounds-> Size, CopyPixelOperation::SourceCopy);
             pictureBox1->Image = screenshot;

     }
     }
```

But with this i'm getting an error as CopyFromScreen:Identifier not found. i tried to search abt this and everywhere it shows syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `CopyFromScreen` is not a custom [free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c) that isn't included in your example, it is [member of the `Graphics` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

<s>You should invoke it as such (as you do with `Graphics::FromImage()` in the line above:</s>

```
graph = Graphics::CopyFromScreen(bounds->X, bounds->Y, 0, 0, bounds-> Size, CopyPixelOperation::SourceCopy);
```

**EDIT**

To address your comment, and my oversight:
`CopyFromScreen` is not static, so it must be invoked on a specific object that you need to create first:

```
graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds->X, bounds->Y, 0, 0, bounds-> Size, CopyPixelOperation::SourceCopy);
```

Comment: when i make the change i'm getting this                                                                                        error C2352: 'System::Drawing::Graphics::CopyFromScreen' : illegal call of non-static member function                                                                  error C3861: 'CopyFromScreen': identifier not found

Comment: i tried to make CopyFromScreen as static                                                i.e     static double CopyFromScreen;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by making `CopyFromScreen` static; it's a library method. Please provide the SSCCE.