# How can I overload an operator for an abstract class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I'm relatively new to C++, and my professor did not go into as much detail into operator overloading as I'd like when I took his class. I'm trying to implement a way to compare objects (using > or <) that all inherit an abstract class, but I'm having trouble with the syntax/logic.

I tried having it be a member of the parent class, but I couldn't figure out how to call a pure virtual function from inside the base class. Then I tried using templates but that's just giving me a headache (my professor didn't go too in-depth on those either).

I'm aware I completely failed in the operator function (and any help with the proper syntax would be appreciated).

```c
#include <iostream>

enum cType { point, maxima, inflection };

class CONSTRAINT {
public:
    //coordinates
    int x, y;
    //gets what type of constraint the object is
    virtual cType getType() = 0; //pure virtual
    //I'm sure this syntax is horrendous and completely wrong.
    //I was just trying to emulate what I found online :(
    bool operator > (const CONSTRAINT &rhs) { 
            //If the constraints have the same type, compare by their x-value
        if (getType() == rhs.getType())
            return (x > rhs.x);
            //Otherwise, it should be point > maxima > inflection
        else
            return (getType() > rhs.getType());
    }
};
class POINT : public CONSTRAINT {
public:
    virtual cType getType() { return point; }
};
class MAXIMA : public CONSTRAINT {
public:
    virtual cType getType() { return maxima; }
};
//I have another inflection class that follows the pattern

int main() {
    POINT point1, point2;
    point1.x = 3;
    point2.x = 5;
    MAXIMA maxima;
    maxima.x = 4;
    std::cout << (point1 > point2);
    std::cout << (point2 > point1);
    std::cout << (maxima > point2);
    std::cout << (point1 > maxima );
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect: 0110
if the program would compile.

Instead I get the following errors:

"the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "CONSTRAINT::getType""

"'cType CONSTRAINT::getType(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CONSTRAINT' to 'CONSTRAINT &'"

Thanks.

Comment: In general it's a Very Bad Idea™ to have a virtual `operator>` or any other virtual binary operator. There are exceptions but they are few and far between. It is a different kind of Very Bad Idea™ to refer to any kind of "type identifier" such as your `enum cType` to perform business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
bool operator > (const CONSTRAINT &rhs)
```

`rhs` is `const`. It cannot be changed inside this method. But...

```
virtual cType getType() = 0; //pure virtual
```

Is not a `const` method. This means the method could change `rhs`, so the compiler refuses to allow it to be called.

Solution: Declare the method `const`

```
virtual cType getType() const = 0; //pure virtual
```

Now the compiler is promised that calling the function will not allow `rhs` to be changed. The compiler will also enforce this and refuse to compile the program if an implementation of `getType` tries to change the object on which it is invoked.

Side notes:

Once a method is declared to be `virtual`, all overrides will also be `virtual`.

The `override` keyword will catch errors if a method should override but doesn't due to a mismatch. Adding `const` to the base class method, but not the derived class method, is a good example of where this is helpful.

Since it looks like this code is taking advantage of runtime polymorphism you may want a virtual destructor in the base class to ensure the correct classes are destroyed should you one day wish to `delete` a derived class through a pointer to the base class.

Wrapping all that up:

```
#include <iostream>

enum cType { point, maxima, inflection };

class CONSTRAINT {
public:
    //coordinates
    int x, y;

    virtual ~CONSTRAINT() = default;
//  ^ added

    //gets what type of constraint the object is
    virtual cType getType() const = 0; //pure virtual
//                          ^ added
    //I'm sure this syntax is horrendous and completely wrong.
    //I was just trying to emulate what I found online :(
    bool operator > (const CONSTRAINT &rhs) {
            //If the constraints have the same type, compare by their x-value
        if (getType() == rhs.getType())
            return (x > rhs.x);
            //Otherwise, it should be point > maxima > inflection
        else
            return (getType() > rhs.getType());
    }
};
class POINT : public CONSTRAINT {
public:
    cType getType() const     override { return point; }
//                  ^ added   ^ added
};
class MAXIMA : public CONSTRAINT {
public:
    cType getType() const     override { return maxima; }
//                  ^ added   ^ added
};
//I have another inflection class that follows the pattern

int main() {
    POINT point1, point2;
    point1.x = 3;
    point2.x = 5;
    MAXIMA maxima;
    maxima.x = 4;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha // < added. prints true and false instead of 1 and 0
              << (point1 > point2) << '\n'
              << (point2 > point1) << '\n'
              << (maxima > point2) << '\n'
              << (point1 > maxima);
    // took advantage of chaining and added newlines to the output for clarity
    return 0;
}
```

Final side note: It is generally recommended that `operator<` be implemented as a [Free Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c). For more on that, and much other wisdom on Operator Overloading, see [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)