# friend function using template classes c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, friend

I made a class which has a friend function and when I declare it there are no problems but, when I write its code it returns me the error:

"Out-of-line definition of 'change' does not match any declaration in 'MyClass '".

Here's the code

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
private:
    T a;
    
public:
    MyClass(T);
    ~MyClass();
    friend void change(MyClass);
};

template <class T>
MyClass <T> :: MyClass(T value) {
    a = value;
}

template <class T>
MyClass <T> :: ~MyClass() {}

template <class T>
void MyClass <T> :: change(MyClass class) { //Out-of-line definition of 'change' does not match any declaration in 'MyClass <T>'
    a = class.a;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `friend` here? What problem do you try to solve? How do you plan to use `change`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`friend void change(MyClass);` does not declare a member function of `MyClass`, it is an instruction for the compiler to grant the free function[¹](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c) `void change(MyClass);` access to private/protected members of `MyClass`.

The free function you grant access to `MyClass` would then have to look that way:

```
template <class S>
void change(MyClass<S> obj) {
    obj.a; // obj.a can be accessed by the free function
}
```

But the `friend` then has to be declared that way in the class:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
private:
    T a;
    
public:
    MyClass(T);
    ~MyClass();

    template <class S>
    friend void change(MyClass<S>);
};
```

But based on `a = class.a` in `change` I think you actually want to have this:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
private:
    T a;
    
public:
    MyClass(T);
    ~MyClass();

    void change(MyClass);
};


template <class T>
MyClass <T> :: MyClass(T value) {
    a = value;
}

template <class T>
MyClass <T> :: ~MyClass() {}

template <class T>
void MyClass <T>::change(MyClass class) {
    a = class.a;
}
```

A member function of `MyClass` can always access all members of any instance of `MyClass`.

1: [What is the meaning of the term “free function” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c)

Comment: Unfortunately, the friend declaration does not declare a function template but a specific overload.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 you could make a member function of a different class a firend.

Comment: well ok, maybe I didnt express myself properly. Removed the comment.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 but yes i know what you mean.

Comment: @t.niese I didn't doubt that ;)

Comment: Which free function? Are you saying that I don't need to be it a friend function?

Comment: @K0sm you don't say in your question why you want to use `friend`, so it is hard to tell. In the current form, I only can tell you how fried is intended to be used.

Comment: I want to have access to the private member of the passed object.

Comment: @K0sm a "free function" is a function that is not a member of a class, in case thats the misunderstanding. In your code `friend void change(MyClass);` does not make `change` a member of the class, it is a free function

Comment: Thank you, my teacher has not explained it and I had to search online. Now I understand the error. Thank you so much for your time guys.

Comment: @K0sm if you want to learn c++ I highly suggest reading a good book. I don't know your teacher, but sadly many of the teachers don't know c++ that well and you often learn bad habits and inaccurate things about c++.