# Nullify the diagonals of the matrix on c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to nullifying elements based on specific diagonals. I've created several classes derived from a base `Matrix` class, each with its own `nullifyAboveMainDiagonal`, `nullifyBelowMainDiagonal`, `nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal`, and `nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal` methods.

However, when I run the code, I'm getting unexpected results.

**Here is my code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
protected:
    int **matrix;
    int size;

public:
    Matrix(int size) : size(size) {
        matrix = new int *[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            matrix[i] = new int[size];
        }
        fill();
    }

    void fill() {
        ifstream file("input_matrix.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    file >> matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }

    int **getMatrix() const {
        return matrix;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    virtual void nullifyAboveMainDiagonal() {}

    virtual void nullifyBelowMainDiagonal() {}

    virtual void nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal() {}

    virtual void nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal() {}

    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            delete[] matrix[i];
        }
        delete[] matrix;
    }
};

class MatrixAboveMainDiagonal : public Matrix {
public:
    MatrixAboveMainDiagonal(int size) : Matrix(size) {
        nullifyAboveMainDiagonal();
    }

    void nullifyAboveMainDiagonal() override {
        int **baseMatrix = getMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                baseMatrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

class MatrixBelowMainDiagonal : public Matrix {
public:
    MatrixBelowMainDiagonal(int size) : Matrix(size) {
        nullifyBelowMainDiagonal();
    }

    void nullifyBelowMainDiagonal() override {
        int **baseMatrix = getMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                baseMatrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

class MatrixAboveSecondaryDiagonal : public Matrix {
public:
    MatrixAboveSecondaryDiagonal(int size) : Matrix(size) {
        nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal();
    }

    void nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal() override {
        int **baseMatrix = getMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
                baseMatrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

class MatrixBelowSecondaryDiagonal : public Matrix {
public:
    MatrixBelowSecondaryDiagonal(int size) : Matrix(size) {
        nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal();
    }

    void nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal() override {
        int **baseMatrix = getMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = size - i; j < size; j++) {
                baseMatrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int size = 2;
    Matrix matrix(size);
    matrix.print();
    cout << endl;

    MatrixAboveMainDiagonal matrixAboveMainDiagonal(size);
    matrixAboveMainDiagonal.print();
    cout << endl;

    MatrixBelowMainDiagonal matrixBelowMainDiagonal(size);
    matrixBelowMainDiagonal.print();
    cout << endl;

    MatrixAboveSecondaryDiagonal matrixAboveSecondaryDiagonal(size);
    matrixAboveSecondaryDiagonal.print();
    cout << endl;

    MatrixBelowSecondaryDiagonal matrixBelowSecondaryDiagonal(size);
    matrixBelowSecondaryDiagonal.print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
0 0 
0 0 


2 0 
2 2  


2 2
0 2 


0 2 
2 2 


2 2 
2 0
```

**Actual output:**

```
0 0 
0 0 


0 0 
0 0  


0 0 
0 0  


0 0 
0 0   


0 0 
0 0
```

I’ve included my input file, `input_matrix.txt`, which contains the following:

```
1 2
3 4
```

I’m not sure why my code is not working as expected. I’ve checked the logic several times and it seems correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Running under the latest version of MSVC, I got the expected output.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: I rewrote your `fill` routine, so I could post this [online compilation](https://onlinegdb.com/z1BPCUAwO) of your code. It runs as expected. Ditto, on why not use `std::vector`. Your program leaks memory when `std::bad_alloc` is thrown _after_ some rows have been successfully allocated, but then allocation fails for a subsequent row.

Comment: There is an argument for eliminating all the derived classes, and writing all the "nullify" functions as [_free functions_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863328/22193627) that take a `Matrix` argument.

Comment: `int main() { Matrix m(10); Matrix m2 = m; }` -- this is a double-free error.  Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal example you posted [runs correctly](https://onlinegdb.com/z1BPCUAwO).

It is likely that the problems you are experiencing have to do with a failure to implement a true "Rule of Five" (or "Rule of Three") class. An assignment or a copy somewhere is likely not working as you intended.

As @Paul Sanders first mentioned in the comments, the easiest solution is to use `std::vector` for this. There is no need for dynamically allocated arrays here.

In addition, it is not clear why you need to use inheritance to zero-out the elements above or below one of the matrix diagonals. Unless there is a reason that was not stated in the question, I would use [*free functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863328/22193627) for that purpose.

##### Memory leaks

When you implement a matrix as a dynamically allocated *array of arrays*, coding the functions for allocation and deallocation becomes a non-trivial task. The constructor you wrote, for instance, leaks memory in the rare circumstance that a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown midway through the allocation process.

Suppose, for example, that rows 0 and 1 are successfully allocated, but then operator `new` throws an exception when it attempts to allocate row 2. In that case, rows 0 and 1, as well as the allocation for your variable `matrix` will all leak.

The program below demonstrates how to fix that.

##### Cross-linked matrices and double-free errors

The failure to implement a full complement of "Rule of Five" (or "Rule of Three") functions means that the compiler will use compiler-supplied defaults for the missing functions. Both the copy constructor and copy-assignment operators will perform member-wise copying. What you need, of course, is to perform deep copying.

With member-wise copy, the `matrix` pointer will simply be copied to the target matrix. You will end up with two matricies that share the same pointer! When the destructor for the second of them is called, you will get a *double free* error. That is what @PaulMcKenzie is alluding to in his comment.

The program below corrects that, by implementing a true "Rule of Five" matrix class.

##### Allocation and deallocation

The program below demonstrates class `SquareMatrix`, which is implemented as a template.

Class `SquareMatrix` uses dynamically allocated arrays, but only for example purposes. You would be better off using `std::vector` instead, and working out the way to use a single vector, rather that a *vector of vectors*.

There is a const version of member function `getMatrix`, to go along with the non-const version, so that the function can be invoked on constant matrices. In practice, however, you should not need to call function `getMatrix` very much, because member function `at` and the `operator[]` functions defined below give you a better way to access matrix elements.

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
class SquareMatrix
{
   enum : std::size_t { zero };
   static_assert(Size > zero);

public:
   using value_type = T;

private:
   value_type** data_{ nullptr };

public:
   SquareMatrix() : data_{ nullptr }
   {
       allocate();
   }

   ~SquareMatrix()
   {
       deallocate(size());
   }

   // ...

   value_type** getMatrix() {
       return data_;
   }

   value_type const** getMatrix() const {
       return data_;
   }

   std::size_t size() const {
       return Size;
   }
};
```

Function `allocate` uses a try-catch block to trap allocation errors. When the allocation of row `i` fails, rows `0` through `i - 1` all need to be deallocated, along with the allocation of the `data_` array. Function `deallocate`, the same function that is called by the destructor, does the work.

```cpp
private:
    void allocate()
    {
        // The initial call to to operator `new` might throw a 
        // `std::bad_alloc`, but if does, there will not be any 
        // rows that need to be deallocated. That is because none 
        // have yet been allocated. For that reason, we do not 
        // place this allocation in a try-catch block.

        data_ = new value_type* [Size]{};

        // Allocate rows.
        // We are here, because the preceding call to operator `new` 
        // was successful. It did not throw a `std::bad_alloc`. 
        // 
        // From here forward, if any call to operator `new` fails, 
        // we must deallocate anything that was previously allocated. 
        // Each call to operator `new`, therefore, is placed within 
        // a try-catch block.

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        {
            try { data_[i] = new value_type[Size]{}; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate(i); throw; }
        }
    }

    void deallocate(std::size_t i) noexcept
    {
        while (i--)
            delete[] data_[i];
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = nullptr;
    }
```

##### "Rule of Four (and a half)"

The term *Rule of Four (and a half)* was coined by Arthur O'Dwyer for his excellent talk at CppCon 2019: [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). It refers to a method of implementing the "Rule of Five" that uses the *copy-and-swap idiom*. You get the extra half, because the copy-assignment operator handles both move and copy operations.

Although the destructor was given above, we include it again here.

```cpp
public:
    // "Rule of Four (and a half)"
    // The extra "half" is the "by-value" copy-assignment operator.
    // It serves for both copy-assignment and move-assignment.
    // 
    //   1. Destructor
    //   2. Copy constructor
    //   3. Move constructor
    //   4. Copy-assignment operator
    //      4.5 Move-assignement operator
    //   5. noexcept swap functions

    // 1. Destructor
    ~SquareMatrix()
    {
        deallocate(size());
    }

    // 2. Copy constructor
    SquareMatrix(SquareMatrix const& that)
        : data_{ nullptr }
    {
        allocate();
        for (auto i{ size() }; i--;) {
            std::copy(that.data_[i], that.data_[i] + size(), this->data_[i]);
        }
    }

    // 3. Move constructor
    SquareMatrix(SquareMatrix&& that) noexcept
        : data_{ std::exchange(that.data_, nullptr) }
    {}

    // 4. Copy-assignment operator
    //    4.5 Move-assignement operator
    SquareMatrix& operator= (SquareMatrix that) noexcept {
        swap(that);
        return *this;
    }

    // 5. noexcept swap functions
    void swap(SquareMatrix& that) noexcept {
        using std::swap;
        swap(this->data_, that.data_);
    }

    friend void swap(SquareMatrix& a, SquareMatrix& b) noexcept {
        a.swap(b);
    }
```

##### Equality operators

For the most part, the things you copy in a copy constructor should be the things you compare in `operator==`. That way, an object and its copy will compare as equal.

When you do a deep-copy, that means you need to do a "deep-compare."

```cpp
    bool operator== (SquareMatrix const& that) const
    {
        for (auto i{ size() }; i--;)
            for (auto j{ size() }; j--;)
                if (this->data_[i][j] != that.data_[i][j])
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!= (SquareMatrix const& that) const
    {
        return !(*this == that);
    }
```

##### Accessing the elements of a matrix

The best way to access a matrix element is by calling member function `at`. There are two versions: one for const objects, and one for non-const. Both include range-checks on the subscripts.

```cpp
    value_type& at(std::size_t const row, std::size_t const col)
    {
        check_row(row);
        check_col(col);
        return data_[row][col];
    }

    value_type const& at(std::size_t const row, std::size_t const col) const
    {
        check_row(row);
        check_col(col);
        return data_[row][col];
    }

private:
    void check_row(std::size_t const row) const
    {
        if (row >= size())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "SquareMatrix: row out of range: " + std::to_string(row));
    }

    void check_col(std::size_t const col) const
    {
        if (col >= size())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "SquareMatrix: column out of range: " + std::to_string(col));
    }
```

For unchecked access, you can use the usual bracket notation (`[]`), but be aware that the `operator[]` functions below are actually returning pointers to a row. When followed by a second bracketed subscript, you get an element from that row. There are many examples in the next section.

```cpp
public:
    value_type* operator[](std::size_t const row)
    {
        // This is a little sketchy, but if you play nice, it works.
        // It is probably better to use function `at`, above.
        return data_[row];
    }

    value_type const* operator[](std::size_t const row) const
    {
        // This is a little sketchy, but if you play nice, it works.
        // It is probably better to use function `at`, above.
        return data_[row];
    }
```

##### Free functions that "nullify" parts of a matrix

The functions below all accept a reference to a matrix as argument, and zero-out the relevant parts of the matrix.

I prefer them to the complicated scheme of inheritance used in the OP.

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyAboveMainDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{ i + one }; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyBelowMainDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < i; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size() - i - one; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = matrix.size() - i; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}
```

##### `SquareMatrix` in action: functions `main` and `test`

The functions below test `SquareMatrix` using types `int` and `double`. The first test is for a matrix with a size of 2; the second, a size of 3.

Function `fill` manages to operate correctly on `int` matrices, while adding `0.5` to the values of a `double` matrix.

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void fill(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    auto const one{ static_cast<T>(1) };
    auto const two{ static_cast<T>(2) };
    auto const half{ static_cast<T>(one / two) };

    auto value{ half };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = ++value;
}
```

Function `test` invokes the four "nullify" functions, while exercizing several other member functions along the way.

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void test(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    // Test copy constructor.
    SquareMatrix<T, Size> 
        a{ matrix },
        b{ matrix },
        c{ matrix },
        d{ matrix };

    // Test equality operator.
    assert(a == matrix);
    assert(b == matrix);
    assert(c == matrix);
    assert(d == matrix);

    // Demonstrate "nullify" functions.
    nullifyAboveMainDiagonal(a);
    std::cout << "nullifyAboveMainDiagonal \n" << a;

    nullifyBelowMainDiagonal(b);
    std::cout << "nullifyBelowMainDiagonal \n" << b;

    nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal(c);
    std::cout << "nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal \n" << c;

    nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal(d);
    std::cout << "nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal \n" << d;

    // Test inequality operator.
    assert(a != matrix);
    assert(b != matrix);
    assert(c != matrix);
    assert(d != matrix);
}
```

Function `main` is the driver. It sets up the two matrices, and passes them to function `test`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    enum : std::size_t { two = 2u, three = 3u };

    SquareMatrix<int, two> m2;
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after construction: \n" << m2;
    std::ifstream ist{ "input_matrix.txt" };
    if (ist.is_open()) {
        ist >> m2;
        ist.close();
    }
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after reading file: \n" << m2;
    test(m2);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    SquareMatrix<double, three> m3;
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after construction: \n" << m3;
    fill(m3);
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after `fill(m3)`: \n" << m3;
    test(m3);

    return 0;
}
```

##### Output

Here is the output:

```
SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after construction:
     0       0
     0       0

SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after reading file:
     1       2
     3       4

nullifyAboveMainDiagonal
     1       0
     3       4

nullifyBelowMainDiagonal
     1       2
     0       4

nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal
     0       2
     3       4

nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal
     1       2
     3       0


SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after construction:
     0       0       0
     0       0       0
     0       0       0

SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after `fill(m3)`:
   1.5     2.5     3.5
   4.5     5.5     6.5
   7.5     8.5     9.5

nullifyAboveMainDiagonal
   1.5       0       0
   4.5     5.5       0
   7.5     8.5     9.5

nullifyBelowMainDiagonal
   1.5     2.5     3.5
     0     5.5     6.5
     0       0     9.5

nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal
     0       0     3.5
     0     5.5     6.5
   7.5     8.5     9.5

nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal
   1.5     2.5     3.5
   4.5     5.5       0
   7.5       0       0
```

##### Putting it all together

This is the complete program.

It includes stream insertion and extraction operators that were not discussed before. The latter is used to input from the same file used in the OP.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
class SquareMatrix
{
    enum : std::size_t { zero };
    static_assert(Size > zero);

public:
    // Template arguments
    using value_type = T;

private:
    // Instance member variables
    value_type** data_{ nullptr };

public:
    // Default constructor
    SquareMatrix() : data_{ nullptr }
    {
        allocate();
    }

private:
    void allocate()
    {
        // The initial call to to operator `new` might throw a 
        // `std::bad_alloc`, but if does, there will not be any 
        // rows that need to be deallocated. That is because none 
        // have yet been allocated. For that reason, we do not 
        // place this allocation in a try-catch block.

        data_ = new value_type* [Size]{};

        // Allocate rows.
        // We are here, because the preceding call to operator `new` 
        // was successful. It did not throw a `std::bad_alloc`. 
        // 
        // From here forward, if any call to operator `new` fails, 
        // we must deallocate anything that was previously allocated. 
        // Each call to operator `new`, therefore, is placed within 
        // a try-catch block.

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        {
            try { data_[i] = new value_type[Size]{}; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate(i); throw; }
        }
    }

    void deallocate(std::size_t i) noexcept
    {
        while (i--)
            delete[] data_[i];
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = nullptr;
    }

public:
    // "Rule of Four (and a half)"
    // The extra "half" is the "by-value" copy-assignment operator.
    // It serves for both copy-assignment and move-assignment.
    // 
    //   1. Destructor
    //   2. Copy constructor
    //   3. Move constructor
    //   4. Copy-assignment operator
    //      4.5 Move-assignement operator
    //   5. noexcept swap functions

    // 1. Destructor
    ~SquareMatrix()
    {
        deallocate(size());
    }

    // 2. Copy constructor
    SquareMatrix(SquareMatrix const& that)
        : data_{ nullptr }
    {
        allocate();
        for (auto i{ size() }; i--;) {
            std::copy(that.data_[i], that.data_[i] + size(), this->data_[i]);
        }
    }

    // 3. Move constructor
    SquareMatrix(SquareMatrix&& that) noexcept
        : data_{ std::exchange(that.data_, nullptr) }
    {}

    // 4. Copy-assignment operator
    //    4.5 Move-assignement operator
    SquareMatrix& operator= (SquareMatrix that) noexcept {
        swap(that);
        return *this;
    }

    // 5. noexcept swap functions
    void swap(SquareMatrix& that) noexcept {
        using std::swap;
        swap(this->data_, that.data_);
    }

    friend void swap(SquareMatrix& a, SquareMatrix& b) noexcept {
        a.swap(b);
    }

    // Custom equality operators
    // In general, an equality operator compares what you copy.
    // That way, a copy will compare equal to the original.
    // 
    // When you write a custom copy constructor, therefore, 
    // you probably need to write custom equality operators 
    // to go with it.
    bool operator== (SquareMatrix const& that) const
    {
        for (auto i{ size() }; i--;)
            for (auto j{ size() }; j--;)
                if (this->data_[i][j] != that.data_[i][j])
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!= (SquareMatrix const& that) const
    {
        return !(*this == that);
    }

    // Other member functions
    value_type** getMatrix() {
        return data_;
    }

    value_type const** getMatrix() const {
        return data_;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return Size;
    }

    value_type& at(std::size_t const row, std::size_t const col)
    {
        check_row(row);
        check_col(col);
        return data_[row][col];
    }

    value_type const& at(std::size_t const row, std::size_t const col) const
    {
        check_row(row);
        check_col(col);
        return data_[row][col];
    }

private:
    void check_row(std::size_t const row) const
    {
        if (row >= size())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "SquareMatrix: row out of range: " + std::to_string(row));
    }

    void check_col(std::size_t const col) const
    {
        if (col >= size())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "SquareMatrix: column out of range: " + std::to_string(col));
    }

public:
    value_type* operator[](std::size_t const row)
    {
        // This is a little sketchy, but if you play nice, it works.
        // It is probably better to use function `at`, above.
        return data_[row];
    }

    value_type const* operator[](std::size_t const row) const
    {
        // This is a little sketchy, but if you play nice, it works.
        // It is probably better to use function `at`, above.
        return data_[row];
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost,
        SquareMatrix const& matrix)
    {
        enum : std::streamsize { width = 6 };
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
                ost << std::setw(width) << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            ost.put('\n');
        }
        ost.put('\n');
        return ost;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (
        std::istream& ist,
        SquareMatrix& matrix)
    {
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
            for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
                ist >> matrix[i][j];
        return ist;
    }
};

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyAboveMainDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{ i + one }; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyBelowMainDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < i; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size() - i - one; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = matrix.size() - i; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = T{};
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void fill(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    auto const one{ static_cast<T>(1) };
    auto const two{ static_cast<T>(2) };
    auto const half{ static_cast<T>(one / two) };

    auto value{ half };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < matrix.size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = ++value;
}

template< typename T, std::size_t Size >
void test(SquareMatrix<T, Size>& matrix)
{
    // Test copy constructor.
    SquareMatrix<T, Size> 
        a{ matrix },
        b{ matrix },
        c{ matrix },
        d{ matrix };

    // Test equality operator.
    assert(a == matrix);
    assert(b == matrix);
    assert(c == matrix);
    assert(d == matrix);

    // Demonstrate "nullify" functions.
    nullifyAboveMainDiagonal(a);
    std::cout << "nullifyAboveMainDiagonal \n" << a;

    nullifyBelowMainDiagonal(b);
    std::cout << "nullifyBelowMainDiagonal \n" << b;

    nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal(c);
    std::cout << "nullifyAboveSecondaryDiagonal \n" << c;

    nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal(d);
    std::cout << "nullifyBelowSecondaryDiagonal \n" << d;

    // Test inequality operator.
    assert(a != matrix);
    assert(b != matrix);
    assert(c != matrix);
    assert(d != matrix);
}

int main()
{
    enum : std::size_t { two = 2u, three = 3u };

    SquareMatrix<int, two> m2;
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after construction: \n" << m2;
    std::ifstream ist{ "input_matrix.txt" };
    if (ist.is_open()) {
        ist >> m2;
        ist.close();
    }
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<int,2> m2, after reading file: \n" << m2;
    test(m2);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    SquareMatrix<double, three> m3;
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after construction: \n" << m3;
    fill(m3);
    std::cout << "SquareMatrix<double,3> m3, after `fill(m3)`: \n" << m3;
    test(m3);

    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### An aside regarding `using namespace std;`

Given the number of textbooks that use it, you may be surprised to learn that professional programmers do not use `using namespace std;` in production code.

Neither should you. See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Instead, professionals just type `std::` every time they need to reference a name from the Standard Library. There are a few exceptions to this, mostly centered around something called *argument-dependent lookup*, but I won't go into them here. (Hint: see function `swap`, a somewhat gratuitous example above.)